# Laravel 5.2 validation distinct gives 'Method does not exist' error

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I'm trying to validate an array on unique ID's. I'm trying to use Laravel's distinct method. When using this method I get this error: `Method [validateDistinct] does not exist`.

I was reading through the documentation saw a difference in the `5.2` and `master` documentation. I'm using version `5.2.19`. When looking at the [version 5.2](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#available-validation-rules) documentation  there is a distinct rule but the [master version](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#available-validation-rules) documentation doesn't have this rule.

So basically my question is: How can I use the distinct validation rule in Laravel 5.2? Or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to upgrade to version 5.2.22